# What is #tfop in Swift Tensorflow and where is it defined?

Tags: swift, tensorflow, tensor

I'm browsing the swift tensorflow code, and stumbled upon instances of

```
var result = #tfop("Mul", a, b)
```

#tfop is well explained in the doc [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/swift/blob/master/docs/GraphProgramExtraction.md), in the sense of 'what it does' but I'm also interested in what is actually is from a language standpoint, or as a function implementation.

What does #tfop represent, beside a handle to the computation graph? why the '#'? Where can I find tfop implementation if I want to? (I browsed the code, but no luck, although I can't guarantee that I didn't miss anything).

Comment: Note that there is also a [swift@tensorflow.org mailing list.](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/d/forum/swift)

Comment: Good point (although I prefer SO's format). Scouting it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

per Chris Lattner:

> #tfop is a “well known” representation used for tensor operations. 
>   It is an internal implementation detail of our stack that isn’t meant
>   to be user visible, and is likely to change over time.
>
> In Swift, "#foo(bar: 42)” is the general syntax used for “macro like”
>   and “compiler magic” operations.  For example C things like **FILE**
>   are spelled as #file in swift:
>   https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0034-disambiguating-line.md
>
> And the “#line 42” syntax used by the C preprocesser is represented
>   with arguments like this: #sourceLocation(file: "foo", line: 42)
>
> In the case of #tfop specifically, this is represented in the Swift
>   AST as an ObjectLiteralExpr, which is the normal AST node for this
>   sort of thing:
>   https://github.com/google/swift/blob/tensorflow/include/swift/AST/Expr.h#L1097
>
> We use special lowering magic to turn it into a SIL builtin
>   instruction in SILGen, which are prefixed with "__tfop_"
>   https://github.com/google/swift/blob/tensorflow/lib/SILGen/SILGenExpr.cpp#L3009
>
> I’d like to move away from using builtin instructions for this, and
>   introduce a first-class sil instruction instead, that’s tracked by:
>   https://github.com/google/swift/issues/16
>
> These instructions are specially recognized by the partitioning pass
>   of GPE:
>   https://github.com/google/swift/blob/tensorflow/lib/SILOptimizer/Mandatory/TFUtilities.cpp#L715

source [here](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/swift/4gxCp7aC06Q)